# Discord.js Bot Command Error: Warn Command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am a beginner at Node.js Coding and recently coded my bot on repl.it
I know that there is something wrong with this code and cannot understand where should I put '{'
Can you please help me <3
Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
 if(message.content.startsWith("!warn"))
 let victim = message.mentions.users.first()
 if(!victim) message.reply("mention someone to warn.")
 else {
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle("Warnings")
 .setDescription(`${victim} got warned by ${message.author}!`)
 .setColor("GREEN")
 .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
 .setTimestamp()
 
 message.channel.send(embed)
 }
});
```

If there are some questions ask it I will really appreciate it if you will help! <3

Can you please send the final version of this code

Comment: After `if(message.content.startsWith("!warn"))` and a closing curly bracket before `});`. Please do make sure to learn some basic JavaScript before hopping into Discord.js Development. It is highly recommended to do so and would help you a lot while debugging your code rather than coming on a support site for such a minor issue (Sorry if I'm being a bit rude).

Comment: I corrected that in my answer to your other question.

Comment: ikr @WorthyAlpaca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed brackets on your opening check for `message.content`

and as a user suggested, try learn some basic JS before coding. I know making a discord bot you want to go straight into in but spend maybe an hour learning the very basics can solve alot of issues for you. :)

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("!warn")) {
    let victim = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (!victim) return message.reply("mention someone to warn.");
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Warnings")
      .setDescription(`${victim} got warned by ${message.author}!`)
      .setColor("GREEN")
      .setFooter(`Moderator : ${message.author.username}`)
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```